# ag grid - manually implemented infinite scroll with autoHeight and performance

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I want to implement an ag grid in some container. As I scroll the container, I add rows to the grid, which has domLayout: 'autoHeight', so it grows in height.
This works fine, and it looks like infinite scrolling without the ag grid knowing. The problem begins when the table gets big and there are a lot of dom elements created.
Is there a way to use domLayout: 'autoHeight' and virtual rows?
Basically letting the grid grow but not actually rendering the rows that are not in the browser viewport? like ag grid does by default when the height is constant?